# Does ngx-swiper-wrapper work with Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7

I am moving from Angular 5 to Angular 7.

My project contains the **ngx-swiper-wrapper** https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-swiper-wrapper]

running `ng build --prod` with Angular 7, reports an error

> ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>
> import { $, addClass, removeClass, hasClass, toggleClass, attr, removeAttr, data, transform, transition as transition$1, on, off, trigger, transitionEnd as transitionEnd$1, outerWidth, outerHeight, offset, css, each, html, text, is, index, eq, append, prepend, next, nextAll, prev, prevAll, parent, parents, closest, find, children, remove, add, styles } from 'dom7/dist/dom7.modular';
>          ^
>         Invalid CSS after "import {": expected "}", was "$, addClass, remove"
>         in /home/victor/src/sabre/sabre-desktop/node_modules/swiper/dist/js/swiper.esm.bundle.js (line 13, column 9)

How do I resolve this situation?

Comment: remove `node_modules` and do a `npm install`, or just try to reinstall `ngx-swiper-wrapper`

Comment: @PierreDuc -thanks but unfortunately did not resolve the matter. same error